# Write .wav file from soundcard output with node js

Tags: node.js, audio, node-modules, audio-recording, streamwriter

I'm a beginner with node js programming and I would like to build two different nodes that are able to capture microphone input and speaker output from a soundcard of a windows machine. The objective is to record calls (both channels) directly from soundcard.

I made the microphone stream with the library naudiodon, very similarly to the example proposed here: [naudiodon npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/naudiodon). It works very well.
This library should support the same on the output, but it is not working for me.

So I've tried other paths without any success. Even the node-core-audio package, where i can set a callback function, i'm not able to pick the buffer and save it to file. This is the code that I try to use to create the stream from the soundcard:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var wav = require('wav');
var engine = require("node-core-audio").createNewAudioEngine();

var writer = new wav.Writer();
writer.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('output.wav'));

var options = {
    inputChannels: 1,
    outputChannels: 1
};

engine.setOptions(options);

engine.addAudioCallback(function (inputBuffer) {

    writer.write(inputBuffer);
    return inputBuffer;
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('Received SIGINT. Stopping recording.');
    writer.end();
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time spent. 
Any suggestion/hint is welcomed

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?